# Python Pandas problem with date conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I'm giving `pandas` a `int` like this: `01142021223007`, the format is `'%m%d%Y%H%M%S'`. this worked perfectly in 2020. For example:

`12192020032906 -> 2020-12-19 03:29:06`

Since 2021 it is giving the wrong date:

`01142021223007 -> 2021-11-04 22:30:07`

Should be `2021-01-14 22:30:07`

Code:

```
self.df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['time'], format='%m%d%Y%H%M%S', errors = 'coerce')
```

I am assuming it just skips the `0` at the beginning of `01142020` and therefore gets to `11 4 2020`. is there a way to explicitly say MMDDYYYY? `format ='%mm%dd%YYYY%HH%MM%SS'` does not work.

the CSV file I am reading from:

```
hum,moist,temp,time
81.1,40,26.30,12192020032906
83.1,38,25.80,12192020033006
85.6,39,25.30,12192020033106
87.3,38,24.90,12192020033206
89.4,38,24.50,12192020033306
90.2,38,24.20,12192020033407
90.9,39,23.90,12192020033506
91.5,38,23.70,12192020033607
92.2,38,23.40,12192020033706
...
57.0,15,25.60,01142021095906
53.6,47,24.30,01142021222407
53.7,44,24.30,01142021222419
54.1,45,24.30,01142021222540
54.9,43,24.30,01142021222706
55.2,43,24.20,01142021222806
55.5,44,24.20,01142021222906
55.7,43,24.20,01142021223007
```

The resulting pandas df:

```
          hum  moist  temp                time
0      44.605     40  25.3 2020-12-19 03:29:06
1      45.705     38  24.8 2020-12-19 03:30:06
2      47.080     39  24.3 2020-12-19 03:31:06
3      48.015     38  23.9 2020-12-19 03:32:06
4      49.170     38  23.5 2020-12-19 03:33:06
...       ...    ...   ...                 ...
22387  29.755     45  23.3 2021-11-04 22:25:40
22388  30.195     43  23.3 2021-11-04 22:27:06
22389  30.360     43  23.2 2021-11-04 22:28:06
22390  30.525     44  23.2 2021-11-04 22:29:06
22391  30.635     43  23.2 2021-11-04 22:30:07
```

Comment: "Im giving pandas a int" - where from - reading it from file or what? Show [mre].

Comment: Added the CSV and pandas df in edit

Comment: @ALollz that makes sense, thank you. would I convert the column after importing from the csv or would I have to edit the csv?

Comment: I would read in the csv with the argument `dtype={'time': 'str'}` and that should solve your problem. Without that pandas tries to be smart and will cast that column to int because they are all numeric-like values.

Comment: Thank you very much, answered!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with leading `0`s. When reading the `csv` pandas sees all numeric-like values and infers that the most suitable dtype is  `int64`. You can prevent this by specifying the column should remain a string with the `dtype` argument, preserving the leading 0s which will give you the proper format.

```
#`data.csv`
hum,moist,temp,time
89.4,38,24.50,12192020033306
90.2,38,24.20,12192020033407
90.9,39,23.90,12192020033506
91.5,38,23.70,12192020033607
92.2,38,23.40,12192020033706
57.0,15,25.60,01142021095906
53.6,47,24.30,01142021222407
53.7,44,24.30,01142021222419
54.1,45,24.30,01142021222540
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype={'time': 'str'})
df['time_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m%d%Y%H%M%S', errors='coerce')
```

---

```
    hum  moist  temp            time            time_new
0  89.4     38  24.5  12192020033306 2020-12-19 03:33:06
1  90.2     38  24.2  12192020033407 2020-12-19 03:34:07
2  90.9     39  23.9  12192020033506 2020-12-19 03:35:06
3  91.5     38  23.7  12192020033607 2020-12-19 03:36:07
4  92.2     38  23.4  12192020033706 2020-12-19 03:37:06
5  57.0     15  25.6  01142021095906 2021-01-14 09:59:06
6  53.6     47  24.3  01142021222407 2021-01-14 22:24:07
7  53.7     44  24.3  01142021222419 2021-01-14 22:24:19
8  54.1     45  24.3  01142021222540 2021-01-14 22:25:40
```

---

Without the `dtype` option, the leading 0s are removed forcing pandas to try to somehow figure out how 114 represents both month and day, and it decides to go with month 11 and day 4

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/al686/Desktop/data.csv')  # time now int64 
df['time_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m%d%Y%H%M%S', errors='coerce')

    hum  moist  temp            time            time_new
0  89.4     38  24.5  12192020033306 2020-12-19 03:33:06
1  90.2     38  24.2  12192020033407 2020-12-19 03:34:07
2  90.9     39  23.9  12192020033506 2020-12-19 03:35:06
3  91.5     38  23.7  12192020033607 2020-12-19 03:36:07
4  92.2     38  23.4  12192020033706 2020-12-19 03:37:06
5  57.0     15  25.6   1142021095906 2021-11-04 09:59:06
6  53.6     47  24.3   1142021222407 2021-11-04 22:24:07
7  53.7     44  24.3   1142021222419 2021-11-04 22:24:19
8  54.1     45  24.3   1142021222540 2021-11-04 22:25:40
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a `date_parser` when reading the data from the file

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
   
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', parse_dates=['time'],
                 date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%d%Y%H%M%S'))
print(df)
```

output

```
     hum  moist  temp                time
0   81.1     40  26.3 2020-12-19 03:29:06
1   83.1     38  25.8 2020-12-19 03:30:06
2   85.6     39  25.3 2020-12-19 03:31:06
3   87.3     38  24.9 2020-12-19 03:32:06
4   89.4     38  24.5 2020-12-19 03:33:06
5   90.2     38  24.2 2020-12-19 03:34:07
6   90.9     39  23.9 2020-12-19 03:35:06
7   91.5     38  23.7 2020-12-19 03:36:07
8   92.2     38  23.4 2020-12-19 03:37:06
9   57.0     15  25.6 2021-01-14 09:59:06
10  53.6     47  24.3 2021-01-14 22:24:07
11  53.7     44  24.3 2021-01-14 22:24:19
12  54.1     45  24.3 2021-01-14 22:25:40
13  54.9     43  24.3 2021-01-14 22:27:06
14  55.2     43  24.2 2021-01-14 22:28:06
15  55.5     44  24.2 2021-01-14 22:29:06
16  55.7     43  24.2 2021-01-14 22:30:07
```